# Make Volley request with AccountManager Token

Tags: android, android-volley, token, accountmanager

I am trying to get the Volley networking library working with Android's AccountManager, which I'm using to get authentication tokens for my REST API. My basic idea is to delay the actual Volley request (actually a GSONRequest extending the default one) until the token has been retrieved from the AccountManager (see TokinzedGsonRequest below). However, this doesn't seem to be working - the GC is working like crazy and the app eventually crashes due to a Stackoverflow Error. Any ideas?

**APIClient.java**

```
public static void makeGsonRequest(Activity context, GsonRequest request, RequestQueue requestQueue) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account account = getAccount(context, accountManager);

    // Delay the request until a token is available
    TokenizedGsonRequest futureRequest = new TokenizedGsonRequest(request, requestQueue);

    Bundle options = new Bundle();
    accountManager.getAuthToken(
            account,
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.authenticator_auth_type),
            options,
            context,
            futureRequest,
            null
    );
}
```

**TokenizedGsonRequest.java (implements AccountManagerCallback)**

```
/**
 * Wrapper around {@link .helpers.GsonRequest} for use with
 * an {@link android.accounts.AccountManager}. The actual {@link com.android.volley.Request}
 * is delayed until a token has been obtained.
 */
private static class TokenizedGsonRequest implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    public static final String TAG = TokenizedGsonRequest.class.getSimpleName();
    private GsonRequest mRequest;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private TokenizedGsonRequest(GsonRequest request, RequestQueue requestQueue) {
        this.mRequest = request;
        this.mRequestQueue = requestQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        Bundle bundle;
        // todo authentication error
        try {
            bundle = result.getResult();
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        String authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received authentication token " + authToken);
            try {
                // Since Volley request urls are final, we have to copy the existing one
                String tokenUrl = API.appendQueryParameter(mRequest.getUrl(), API.TOKEN, authToken);
                GsonRequest requestCopy = new GsonRequest<>(
                        mRequest.getMethod(),
                        tokenUrl,
                        mRequest.getClass(),
                        mRequest.getHeaders(),
                        mRequest.getRequestObject(),
                        mRequest.getListener(),
                        mRequest.getErrorListener() // todo wrap error listener for retry on 400
                );
                // Retain the original request tag for cancellation
                requestCopy.setTag(TAG);
                mRequestQueue.add(requestCopy);
            } catch (AuthFailureError e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                // todo bubble up
            }
        } else {
            // todo authentication error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself and managed to integrate authenticated Volley requests with the AccountManager by using header-based authentication. As it turns out, cloning the request doesn't work very well when using GSON because the parametrized information is lost.

**APIClient.java**

```
/**
 * Ensures to authenticate a given {@link com.android.volley.Request} through the
 * {@link android.accounts.AccountManager}.
 * @param request
 * @param listener
 */
public void makeRequest(Request request, AuthenticatedRequestCallback.AuthenticationErrorListener listener) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(mContext);
    Account account = getAccount(accountManager);

    // Delay the request until a token from the account manager is available
    request.setRetryPolicy(new TokenRetryPolicy());
    AuthenticatedRequestCallback requestCallback = new AuthenticatedRequestCallback(
            request, mRequestQueue, listener);

    // Retrieve token and execute initial request
    Bundle options = new Bundle();
    accountManager.getAuthToken(
            account,
            mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.authenticator_auth_type),
            options,
            mContext,
            requestCallback,
            null
    );
}
```

**AuthenticatedRequestCallback.java**

```
/**
 * Wrapper around {@link com.votilab.votiapp.helpers.GsonRequest} for use with
 * an {@link android.accounts.AccountManager}. The actual {@link com.android.volley.Request}
 * is executed when an authentication token has been obtained.
*/
public class AuthenticatedRequestCallback implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
public static final String TAG = AuthenticatedRequestCallback.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_PARAM = "token";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER = "X-Auth-Token";

private Request mRequest;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private final AuthenticationErrorListener mErrorListener;

/**
 * Callback interface to listen for errors thrown by the
 * {@link android.accounts.AccountManager}.
 */
public interface AuthenticationErrorListener {
    public void onAuthenticationError(AuthenticatorException e);
}

public AuthenticatedRequestCallback(Request request,RequestQueue requestQueue,
                                    AuthenticationErrorListener listener) {
    this.mRequest = request;
    this.mRequestQueue = requestQueue;
    this.mErrorListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
    Bundle bundle;
    try {
        bundle = result.getResult();
    } catch (OperationCanceledException | IOException e) {
        if (mErrorListener != null) {
            mErrorListener.onAuthenticationError(new AuthenticatorException(e.getMessage()));
        }
        return;
    } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
        if (mErrorListener != null) {
            mErrorListener.onAuthenticationError(e);
        }
        return;
    }

    String authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received authentication token " + authToken); // todo remove log message
        try {
            ((AuthorizableRequest) mRequest)
                    .addHeader(AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER, authToken);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(mRequest.toString()
                    + " must implement " + AuthorizableRequest.class.getSimpleName());
        }
        // Queue the request for execution
        mRequestQueue.add(mRequest);
    } else {
        if (mErrorListener != null) {
            mErrorListener.onAuthenticationError(
                    new AuthenticatorException("Authentication token is empty."));
        }
    }
}
```

}

**AuthorizableRequest.java**

```
/**
 * An interface for implementation in a {@link com.android.volley.Request} to
 * support custom authentication headers.
 */
public interface AuthorizableRequest {

    public void addHeader(String header, String value);

}
```

Assuming a proper implementation of a custom Authenticator extending the  AbstractAccountAuthenticator, you should be able to make requests from your activity like this while authentication is taken care of behind the scenes:

```
mApiClient.makeRequest(someVolleyRequest, new AuthenticatedRequestCallback.AuthenticationErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(AuthenticatorException e) {
                    // something went wrong in the account manager
                }
            });
```